# How do I get GROUP BY to pick the "earliest" result?

Tags: sql, mysql, ruby-on-rails

Suppose I'm trying to catalog Banks and Branches, where a Bank has multiple branches via `branches.bank_id`. Each Branch has an awesomeness factor `branches.awesomeness`.

How would I structure a query that returns a list of Banks sorted by their least awesome branch?

I have the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `banks`
  INNER JOIN `branches` ON `branches`.`bank_id` = `banks`.`id`
  GROUP BY `banks`.`id`
  ORDER BY `branches`.`awesomeness` ASC;
```

When I try this, the branch whose information gets grouped in with any given bank is not the least awesome branch (which is the one that shows up earliest on the results removing the `GROUP BY` statement).

How shall I accomplish this?

This is meant to go with Rails, so if it is more convenient to use arel-style syntax or take into consideration Rails-specific requirements, feel free to throw those in.

Comment: show some more of your schema, and expected result, I'm somewhat lost on what 'earliest' means? time/date? or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not understand why you want to use `GROUP BY` if you also want to get the branch data.
Remove the `GROUP BY` from your query, and update the sorting to:
`ORDER BY branches.bank_id, branches.awesomeness`

If you insinst on groupping, use the `MIN()` aggregate function to get the least awesomeness for each group.

`ORDER BY MIN(branches.awesomeness) ASC;`

---

Update: If you want a hybrid of both, and want to sort banks by "least awesomeness" and the branches in the bank by awesomeness them self, use this query:

```
SELECT b.*, r.*, brs.MinAw
FROM banks b
    INNER JOIN branches r ON r.bank_id = b.id
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT bank_id, MIN(awesomeness) MinAw
        FROM branches
        GROUP BY bank_id
    ) brs ON b.id = brs.bank_id
ORDER BY brs.MinAw, r.awesomeness;
```

Comment: Thanks, Mr. The Scrum Meister. The aggregate functions are something I'm still coming to wrap my head around. Your recommendations seems to work just fine, though. I also fully agree with your assessment that grouping is not necessary given what I've implied by the question. My real purpose for the question is one in which grouping is useful (namely that the querier expects only one of each "bank"), and I felt it more helpful to assert that I was looking for grouping rather than explain the convoluted situation that necessitates it.

Comment: @steven-xu If you do use grouping, that would imply that you want the group to be sorted, however the individual branches them self (within a group) do **not** need to be sorted. for that use the `MIN` function. I would like to let you know, that while your query would sort properly, since you are selecting `*`, the **branch** row that will be returned will be random for each bank (since you are grouping by `bank` but selecting `branch` to).

Comment: What's the difference between using your nested query style to produce the min awesomeness and simply including `MIN(awesomeness)` among the select parameters?

Comment: @steven-xu The nested query will let you select all banks **and all branches**, Grouping by banks will give you all the banks, and 1 random branch row.

Answer (score 1):

Supplementary to Scrum Meisters answer:

- JOIN syntax joins the records from a parent to child, and when the child can have more than one record associated to the parent record -- you'll get duplicates.
- `DISTINCT` won't help when selecting all columns from all the tables involved, because the entire row needs to be duplicated for DISTINT to remove it.  In this example there, will be different branch information for each row.
- MySQL's `GROUP BY` support omitting columns is used as a crutch by most - few other databases support this, so it won't work if you move to SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL...  The other issue with MySQL's GROUP BY support is the column value from those not defined in the GROUP BY and not within an aggregate function will be arbitrary - the larger the data set, the less likely you can guarantee the same output consistently.

Comment: I am attempting to transition to PostgreSQL, and your third point proves to be extremely correct. I still can't manage to get this functionality to work as a scope using psql.

Comment: @Steven Xu: If PostgreSQL 8.4+, re-write to use ROW_NUMBER() (sadly, an analytic function MySQL doesn't support).

Comment: I'm sorry; could you elaborate on what you mean by the hint to use ROW_NUMBER? I looked up the documentation, and it doesn't appear to be related to my current quandry.

Comment: @Steven Xu: Create a new question & reply with a link, and I will.

Comment: Gotta catch the Super Bowl, but I'll get this up tonight. Thanks for your clairvoyant help!

Comment: @Steven Xu: Cool, I got to run errands too but will devote time when you've got it up.

Comment: I've put up the hopefully not to convoluted question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918098. Any review would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

maybe?

```
select DISTINCT bank_id from branches
ORDER BY awesomeness desc;
```