# How to group results from a query based on one-to-many association by some criterion in the "many"?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Please forgive the awkward title. I had a hard time distilling my question into one phrase. If anyone can come up with a better one, feel free.

I have the following simplified schema:

```
vendors
  INT id

locations
  INT id
  INT vendor_id
  FLOAT latitude
  FLOAT longitude
```

I am perfectly capable of return a list of the nearest vendors, sorted by proximity, limited by an approximation of radius:

```
SELECT * FROM locations
WHERE latitude IS NOT NULL AND longitude IS NOT NULL
  AND ABS(latitude - 30) + ABS(longitude - 30) < 50
ORDER BY ABS(latitude - 30) + ABS(longitude - 30) ASC
```

I can't at this moment find my way around the repetition of the order/limit term. I initially attempted aliasing it as "distance" among the `SELECT` fields, but psql told me that this alias wasn't available in the `WHERE` clause. Fine. If there's some fancy pants way around this, I'm all ears, but on to my main question:

**What I'd like to do is to return a list of vendors, each joined with the closest of its locations, and have this list ordered by proximity and limited by radius.**

So supposing I have 2 vendors, each with two locations. I want a query that limits the radius such that only one of the four locations is within it to return that location's associated vendor alongside the vendor itself. If the radius encompassed all the locations, I'd want vendor 1 presented with the closest between its locations and vendor 2 with the closest between its locations, ultimately ordering vendors 1 and 2 based on the proximity of their closest location.

In MySQL, I managed to get the closest location in each vendor's row by using `GROUP BY` and then `MIN(distance)`. But PostgreSQL seems to be stricter on the usage of `GROUP BY`.

I'd like to, if possible, avoid meddling with the `SELECT` clause. I'd also like to, if possible reuse the `WHERE` and `ORDER` parts of the above query. But these are by no means absolute requirements.

I have made hackneyed attempts at `DISTINCT ON` and `GROUP BY`, but these gave me a fair bit of trouble, mostly in terms of me missing mirrored statements elsewhere, which I won't elaborate in great detail on now.

---

## Solution

I ended up adopting a solution based off [OMG Ponies' excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918098/how-to-group-results-from-a-query-based-on-one-to-many-association-by-some-criter/4918258#4918258).

```
SELECT vendors.* FROM (
  SELECT locations.*, 
    ABS(locations.latitude - 2.1) + ABS(locations.longitude - 2.1) AS distance,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY locations.locatable_id, locations.locatable_type
      ORDER BY ABS(locations.latitude - 2.1) + ABS(locations.longitude - 2.1) ASC) AS rank
    FROM locations
    WHERE locations.latitude IS NOT NULL
    AND locations.longitude IS NOT NULL
    AND locations.locatable_type = 'Vendor'
  ) ranked_locations
INNER JOIN vendors ON vendors.id = ranked_locations.locatable_id
WHERE (ranked_locations.rank = 1)
  AND (ranked_locations.distance <= 0.5)
ORDER BY ranked_locations.distance;
```

Some deviations from OMG Ponies' solution:

- Locations are now polymorphically associated via `_type`. A bit of a premise change.
- I moved the join outside the subquery. I don't know if there are performance implications, but it made sense in my mind to see the subquery as a getting of locations and partitioned rankings and then the larger query as an act of bringing it all together.
- *minor* Took away table name aliasing. Although I'm plenty used to aliasing, it just made it harder for me to follow along. I'll wait until I'm more experienced with PostgreSQL before working in that flair.

Comment: table name aliasing is (mostly) a point of style: some people always use them, some people avoid them. moving calculations into an inner query and then joining up with additional data "afterwards" makes complete sense to me. Looking at explain output is the way to see if there is a performance impact; my gut feel in this case is that it may provide a minor improvement due to having to hold less data during the sort implied by the ranking function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For PostgreSQL 8.4+, you can use [analytics like ROW_NUMBER](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-window.html):

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM (SELECT v.*,
               t.*,
               ABS(t.latitude - 30) + ABS(t.longitude - 30) AS distance,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY v.id
                                     ORDER BY ABS(t.latitude - 30) + ABS(t.longitude - 30)) AS rank
          FROM VENDORS v
          JOIN LOCATIONS t ON t.vendor_id = v.id
         WHERE t.latitude IS NOT NULL 
           AND t.longitude IS NOT NULL) x
  WHERE x.rank = 1
    AND x.distance < 50
ORDER BY x.distance
```

I left the filtering on distance, in case the top ranked value was over 50 so the vendor would not appear.  Remove the distance check being less than 50 portion if you don't want this to happen.

ROW_NUMBER will return a distinct sequential value that resets for every vendor in this example.  If you want duplicates, you'd need to look at using DENSE_RANK.

See [this article for emulating ROW_NUMBER on PostgreSQL pre-8.4](http://explainextended.com/2009/05/11/postgresql-emulating-row_number/).

Comment: Any reason to call prefer `ROW_NUMBER()` over `RANK()`? Granted, I understand neither, but the latter appears to produce the same results and conveniently doesn't require an alias given your top-level query.

Comment: I found the [part of the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-window.html) that compares them, but I'm having a hard time nuancing out the difference.

Comment: Sorry to answer my own question, but I discovered a reason for which `ROW_NUMBER` is preferable for my purposes. Two "locations" will never tie for `ROW_NUMBER`. While, in practice, a tie in distance would be exceedingly rare, the edge case popped up quite easily in my test cases and should be taken care of. If you have anything to add, let me know.

Comment: Alright, after an hour of fidgeting around, I finally got all my unit tests to pass again! I posted the working code at the end of my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4918098/203137). I appreciate all the time you've spent so far. If I could trouble you to critique my final effort, I'm sure I could learn very much!

Comment: @Steven Xu: Don't see the need for `AND ranked_locations.locatable_type = 'Vendor'` because that's all the ranked_locations is going to return -- not a performance issue, just readability.  Have to check the EXPLAIN to see if the INNER JOIN is better off inside the ranked_locations or outside.  I recommend using table aliases, and putting them on all columns to make the query readable to others -- you know where the stuff comes from, but someone else won't.

Comment: @OMG: You're very correct about the first point. Thanks! I'm afraid I'm not quite understanding you point about aliasing. If I'm going to prefix the columns with the full table name, how would aliasing the table name and prefixing with that enhance readability?

Comment: @Steven Xu: To know which table the column comes from, without having to type the entire table name.

Comment: I see. Very well then. Thanks for all your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL extends GROUP BY and not all columns are required to be aggregates. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

I have seen many questions here with the same issue. The trick is to get the nececssary columns in a subquery and then self join it in the outer query:

```
create temp table locations (id int, vender_id int, latitude int, longitude int);
CREATE TABLE
insert into locations values
        (1, 1, 50, 50),
        (2, 1, 35, 30),
        (3, 2, 5, 30)
;
SELECT
     locations.*, distance
     FROM
     (
          SELECT 
              vender_id,
              MIN(ABS(latitude - 30) + ABS(longitude - 30)) as distance
              FROM locations
              WHERE latitude IS NOT NULL AND longitude IS NOT NULL
                  GROUP BY vender_id
      ) AS min_locations
      JOIN locations ON
           ABS(latitude - 30) + ABS(longitude - 30) = distance
           AND min_locations.vender_id = locations.vender_id
       WHERE distance < 50
       ORDER BY distance
;
 id | vender_id | latitude | longitude | distance 
----+-----------+----------+-----------+----------
  2 |         1 |       35 |        30 |        5
  3 |         2 |        5 |        30 |       25
```

Comment: I have to say I am impressed at your creative `ABS(latitude - 30) + ABS(longitude - 30) = distance` join. Your solution makes much sense to me an is even portable back to MySQL. Is there really no other way, though, to "drag along" the rest of the row responsible for the MIN(...) in the subquery `min_locations`? I have to say that that seems like it would be a very useful function. While I understand psql's fussiness on showing ungrouped, unaggregated fields (it certainly makes sense for an "average" aggregation), it would be nice to see it for "min". I guess that's just blurring the lines.

Comment: An unfortunate consequence of your otherwise unconventional join solution is that it seems to run into trouble when two locations (under the same vendor if you include the vendor_id constraint on the join conditions) have the same distance. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Steven Xu:Postgresql follows the standard with GROUP BY. MySQL is an extension and non grouped rows are 'indeterminate' (according to doc) in how they are picked.  To ensure only one row is picked per vendor you can use a group by in the outer query where all columns are grouped except for min(id). As for an unconventional goes, windowing functions are fairly new - especially for open source. SQL has been around since the 70's. The tables must have been joined somehow ... :-)